# python function that contains a dict, takes a key and returns a value from that dict

Tags: python, function, dictionary, key, key-value

I'm trying to write a function that accepts a particular dictionary key and returns that dict value as a string. Below I'm trying to pass in a key that can be 1-4 and have it return the associated value. How do I properly do this? Here's my best guess, which just returns all the chapters, which isn't what I want.

```
def function(chapter_key):
    chapters = {
        1: '["chapter_1"]',
        2: '["chapter_2"]',
        3: '["chapter_3"]',
        4: '["chapter_4"]'
    }
    return chapters
```

so calling function(1) would return "chapter_1"

edited a bit after some comments.

Comment: Are your values always lists with one string entry?

Comment: Is this a valid python syntax ??

Comment: no I doubt this is valid syntax, that's where I'm going wrong. Is likey the syntax and how to actually call the function with the appropriate key to get the value I'm looking for. Thats why im asking for help. i cant find an example of the proper method. This was just a best guess for what I'm asking to do.

Comment: correct way to define a dictionary `chapters = {1: '["chapter_1"]',2: '["chapter_2"]',3: '["chapter_3"]',4: ["chapter_4"]'}` Then `return chapters[chapter_key]`

Comment: I can do that, but then how do I pass in the key and get the value when using a function? If I dont use a function then I can totally follow the python docs and retrieve the value with chapters[1] which would return the string I want.

Comment: Why are people downvoting my question? It's useful to see that I was going about something the wrong way so others can benefit from the same understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{'key':'value'}.get('key', None)` returns `'value'`

Keep in mind that methods are objects, and anything that expects a function can take a method off of an object, too.

if you MUST make your own function...

```
NO_KEY = object()

def f(ch):
    chap = {
        1: 'foo',
    }
    return chap.get(ch, NO_KEY)

chapter = f(1)
print(chapter if chapter is not NO_KEY else 'There was no chapter')
```

Here, I am using the two-argument form of dict.get.  The second argument is the default value if the key (the first argument) is not present in the dictionary.  You would do this to check if the value returned is useful to you.  By default, without a second argument, .get will return None, but if None is a valid value in your dictionary, it's not very useful as a sentinel value.

It is kind of long winded way of saying 'use .get'

Comment: Thank you. So sounds like using a function is just an extra unnecessary step for what I'm asking. That's probably why I wasn't finding examples for it.

Comment: The second argument to .get is the default if the dictionary does not contain the key in the first argument.  This prevents the application from crashing and burning when a key does not exist.  Its quite a bit cheaper than wrapping it in a try...except structure

Comment: I know how dict.get works, I meant `None` is returned by default so why add it, if you were going to add something it would maybe be better to actually output something like "key does not exist"?

Comment: ... Habit from getattr.  Not a bad habit, though.  None is the 'Key does not exist' indicator.  If your dict actually contains None as a valid value, some other sentinel value can be used, like object() (for the instance, to use in ``is`` checks.  Don't think it is fitting to add to the answer though)

Comment: I meant as a way of explaining what `dict.get` does, you have explained nothing as to what your code is doing or what the second parameter to `.get` is for bar use a value that will be returned by default anyway

Answer (score 0):

This would work I guess:

```
def function(chapter_key):
    chapters = {
        1 : 'chapter_1',
        2 : 'chapter_2',
        3 : 'chapter_3',
        4 : 'chapter_4'
    }

    chapter_name = chapters[chapter_key]
    return chapter_name
```

Comment: What if chapter_key is 5... or '5'?  Use two argument .get() instead.

Comment: You are absolutely right - have to control keys separately and have a valid key as an argument. The method you are proposing is absolutely valid, of course, without the need for error handling.